# How to set animation for child node from scn file in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, arkit

I have 3d train model with track. Train folder is parent node and it has two child node called rail and electrictrain. When reference is detected on top of reference image 3d train track will be shown and slowly 3d train model animate on track node with smooth animation.

here is my art.assets.scn file screenshots:

[image]

Here is my reference image detection code which i have used renderer delegate method:

```
  //train 3d model plane
  let trainBottomPlane = SCNPlane(width: 0.08, height: 0.02)
  trainBottomPlane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.0)
  let trainBottomNode = SCNNode(geometry: trainBottomPlane)
  trainBottomNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi/2
  trainBottomNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -0.038)
  let overlaytrainNode = self.getNode(withImageName: "trainModel")
  print("overlay::\((overlaytrainNode))")
```

Here is code for getting scn file child node:

```
lazy var trainNode: SCNNode = {
    guard let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/train.scn"),
        let node = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "train", recursively: false) else { return SCNNode() }

    let newValue = node.childNode(withName: "ElectricTrain", recursively: false)
    print("newvalue::::\(newValue)")
    newValue.position = SCNVector3(1.0  , 0.05, 0.0)

    node.scale = SCNVector3(0.0025, 0.0025, 0.0025)
    node.position = SCNVector3(-0.07, 0.00, 0.0)
    node.eulerAngles.x = -.pi/2
    node.eulerAngles.y = .pi
    node.eulerAngles.z = .pi/2

    return node
}()

func getNode(withImageName name: String) -> SCNNode {
    var node = SCNNode()
    switch name {
    case "3dMap": 
        node = dmapNode
    case "3dGraph":
        node = dgraphNode
    case "trainModel":
        node = trainNode
    default:
        break
    }
    return node
}
```

My questions: 1. How to get child node and set position?
              2. How to do smooth animation for train to move on track when reference iamge detected?

Any help much appreciated pls..